# Date column in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a simple question on date column in oracle

Suppose I have a table called orders and few fields in it like orderid, orderdate, orderno etc..

I want the info like orderno, no of orders made on a particular day.
To test this, I have created few orders on my test application. I have written the below query

```
SELECT orderid,orderno FROM orders WHERE orderdate='29-SEP-16';
```

the date format I mentioned in the query is correct. The above query returns nothing. If I change the where condition to `>'28-SEP-16'` it works.

Why my 1st query doesn't work?

Comment: are the times stored with the dates? If so, then you won't get an equality match unless the correct time is provided, because Sept 29 @ 2pm is not equal to Sept 29 @ 3:15pm. If this is the case, then you can use date parts to compare only the day, month, and year (and not time).

Comment: It sounds like you are storing dates as text?

Comment: The column has been created as type date and I'm not storing the time any where. The format is 'DD-MON-YY'

Comment: Maybe you should use `TO_DATE` function: `orderdate=TO_DATE('29-SEP-16')`.

Comment: I tried, still returns null.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the query and how you execute it

Comment: Try this condition: `>28-SEP-16 AND <30-SEP-16`. What will it display?

Comment: [Oracle `Date` columns have a time component](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847).  How did you insert your date data?  Most likely the issue is the time portion of the field.

Comment: I tried between and it works!! But I want to know why does orderdate='29-SEP-16' doesn't work?

Comment: because there is *always* a time portion.  it is pretty easy to make that part zero when you insert

Comment: Maybe this will work: `TO_DATE(orderdate)=TO_DATE('29-SEP-2016')`.

Comment: If orderdate is a date field, then it should be checked against a date explicitly rather than relying on implicit conversion from string to date. If it's not a date field... why not? If you wish to do various comparisons, especially before/after, then it should be. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-sep/o54asktom-2279184.html

Comment: It is a date field and I'm checking it with the value as it is, stored in the database. When I do, select orderdate from orders the orderdate displays as 29-SEP-16, but when you do where orderdate='29-SEP-16' it doesn't work. I also tried altering the session to 'DD-MON-YY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `date` column does not have a format (well, a `date` does have a particular packed binary representation that is very much non human readable).  Oracle will attempt to implicitly cast a string to a date using your session's `nls_date_format` and will use the session's `nls_date_format` to display a string representation of a date (assuming your client application does not override these).  You should not rely on implicit data type conversion, however.  You should really use date literals or use `to_date` to do an explicit cast.

A `date` column always includes a time.  Your `nls_date_format` may or may not include a time component so the time component may or may not be displayed.  But it is always there.

Assuming your `nls_date_format` is `dd-mon-rr`, the query

```
SELECT orderid,orderno 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE orderdate='29-SEP-16';
```

will show you all orders where `orderdate` is Sept 29, 2016 at midnight.  It will not show rows where the time component is anything after midnight.  You can fix that by doing an inequality comparison.  Using a date literal, that would be

```
SELECT orderid,orderno 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE orderdate >= date '2016-09-29';
```

or

```
SELECT orderid,orderno 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE orderdate >= date '2016-09-29'
   AND orderdate <  date '2016-09-30';
```

if you want to specify a range.  Alternately, you could truncate the time portion of `orderdate` and do an equality comparison.  I'll show the use of `to_date` for explicit conversions here

```
SELECT orderid,orderno 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE trunc(orderdate) = to_date( '29-SEP-16', 'DD-MON-RR' )
```

If you do this, however, you are likely to need a function-based index on `trunc(orderdate)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It makes more sense now. I tried the query and it worked!