# How to cast DATE column to get proper aggregation in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by, casting

I have previously posted in: [Aggregating based on grouping of multiple columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834881/aggregating-based-on-grouping-of-multiple-columns) After two weeks of trying subqueries and analytical functions to do a basic COUNT and GROUP BY of 7 columns, I think that I discovered my source of error was that the DATE field. (Through trial and error of all of the other columns, the COUNT properly aggregates to 1 count row grouped by the 6 columns.)

Now, the question remains: is there something that I can do to ensure that I am only bringing back distinct dates for the format DD MMM YY (without times)? Based on this post, it seems like perhaps the issue is that I am bringing back times with the date even though ORACLE only shows the date portion? [Date column in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838501/date-column-in-oracle). Any pointers on CASTING the DATE_STARTED value so that I can use the initial WHERE clause to filter my initial search and then later use DATE like a string to make a UUID?

My code so far (with some code removed e.g.,  … = CASE STATEMENT to create an additional column, ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS ):

```
WITH TALLY as (
SELECT PERSON.NAME, PERSON.PHASE, TEST.DATE_STARTED, TEST.ANALYSIS, SPECIMEN.GROUP, TEST.STATUS,
 ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE...
    FROM DB.TEST
    INNER JOIN
    DB.SAMPLE ON
    TEST.SPECIMEN_NUMBER = SPECIMEN.SPECIMEN_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN 
    DB.PRODUCT ON
    SPECIMEN.PERSON = PERSON.NAME
    INNER JOIN
    DB.ANALYSIS ON
    TEST.ANALYSIS = ANALYSIS.NAME
    WHERE PERSON.NAME = 'Joe'
    AND TEST.DATE_STARTED >= '20-DEC-18' AND TEST.DATE_STARTED <='03-APR-19'
    AND PERSON.PHASE = 'PHASE1'
    ORDER BY TEST.DATE_STARTED),

SUMMARY_COMBO AS (SELECT DISTINCT(TALLY.DATE_STARTED), CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(DATE_STARTED,ANALYSIS),STATUS), GROUP), ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS) AS UUID,
TALLY.NAME, TALLY.PHASE,TALLY.ANALYSIS,TALLY.GROUP, TALLY.STATUS, ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS
FROM TALLY)

SELECT SUMMARY_COMBO.NAME,SUMMARY_COMBO.PHASE,SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS, SUMMARY_COMBO.GROUP,SUMMARY_COMBO.STATUS,SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS,SUMMARY_COMBO.UUID,
COUNT(SUMMARY_COMBO.UUID) AS S_COUNT
FROM SUMMARY_COMBO
GROUP BY SUMMARY_COMBO.NAME,SUMMARY_COMBO.PHASE,SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS,SUMMARY_COMBO.STATUS,SUMMARY_COMBO.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS,SUMMARY_COMBO.UUID
HAVING COUNT(*) >=1
ORDER BY UUID;
```

This yields something like this:[UUID produces COUNT for each date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQQme.png)

Ideally, I could also include the DATE_STARTED as well. When I currently try to include DATE_STARTED, the aggregation does not work, as the S_COUNT is 1 for each permutation.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you could provide sample data to replace your `TALLY` Common Table Expression and a sample of how you are expecting the results, that would make helping you much easier.

Comment: The syntax for date literals is `date '2018-12-20'`, not `'20-DEC-18'`. See [Oracle SQL Language Reference: Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Answer (score 1):

> perhaps the issue is that I am bringing back times with the date even though ORACLE only shows the date portion?

Very likely, yes. Oracle's `DATE` datatype stores the date *and* time, which might be misleading as opposed to databases that have separate `date` and `datetime` datatypes. You can change the default string format of dates to confirm that:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

Then rerun the query and see the results you get.

A simple solution to remove the time portion is `trunc()`:

```
trunc(test.date_started)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the query below should give you what you need.  Using `TRUNC` on a `DATE` column in Oracle strips the time from the date. You can then use that in your `GROUP BY` to get the number of tests that were done on each day.

I also changed your date parameters to use the `TO_DATE` function. It is bad practice to use a 2 digit year.  It is also a good idea to case your parameters to dates when they are going to be used against a `DATE` column.

```
  SELECT PERSON.NAME,
         PERSON.PHASE,
         TEST.ANALYSIS,
         SPECIMEN.GROUPr,
         TEST.STATUS,
         ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS,
         TO_CHAR (TRUNC (TEST.DATE_STARTED), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
             AS date_started,
         TO_CHAR (TRUNC (TEST.DATE_STARTED), 'DD-MON-YYYY') || TEST.ANALYSIS || TEST.STATUS || ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS
             AS uuid,
         COUNT (*)
             AS s_count
    FROM DB.TEST
         INNER JOIN DB.SAMPLE ON TEST.SPECIMEN_NUMBER = SPECIMEN.SPECIMEN_NUMBER
         INNER JOIN DB.PRODUCT ON SPECIMEN.PERSON = PERSON.NAME
         INNER JOIN DB.ANALYSIS ON TEST.ANALYSIS = ANALYSIS.NAME
   WHERE     PERSON.NAME = 'Joe'
         AND TEST.DATE_STARTED >= TO_DATE ('20-DEC-2018')
         AND TEST.DATE_STARTED <= TO_DATE ('03-APR-2019')
         AND PERSON.PHASE = 'PHASE1'
GROUP BY PERSON.NAME,
         PERSON.PHASE,
         TEST.ANALYSIS,
         SPECIMEN.GROUPr,
         TEST.STATUS,
         ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS,
         TRUNC (TEST.DATE_STARTED)
ORDER BY TRUNC (TEST.DATE_STARTED),
         TEST.ANALYSIS,
         TEST.STATUS,
         ANALYSIS.ANALYSIS_TYPE_ALIAS;
```

Comment: Don't use implicit date conversions (i.e. `TO_DATE('20-DEC-2018')`); instead, you should either include an explicit format model `TO_DATE('20-DEC-2018','DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')` or use a date literal `DATE '2018-12-20'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly convert `DATE_STARTED` to a varchar using the format you prefer:

```
TO_CHAR(test.date_started, 'DD MON YYYY')
```

Using this expression instead of all the instances of `TEST.DATE_STARTED` you have in your query should fix the issue.